# Select count distinct to list instead of count

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the following query:

```
select distinct(ord_nbr), ord_line_rate_nbr, count(distinct(ntwrk_key)), count(distinct(stn_key))
    from my_table
    where ord_nbr in (select distinct(ord_nbr) from another_table)
    group by 1,2
    order by 1 desc
 ;
```

I would like to get ride of `count(distinct(ntwrk_key)), count(distinct(stn_key))` and instead replace this with a list of the distinct values.

So say for row 1, `count(distinct(ntwrk_key)) == 5`.
Instead I'd want to return `[ntwk1, ntwk4, ntwk5, ntwk9, ntwk12]`

EDIT:Say we have this table

```
+---------+-------------------+-----------+----------+
| ord_nbr | ord_line_rate_nbr | ntwrk_key | stn_key\ |
+---------+-------------------+-----------+----------+
|   12345 |                 1 | NTWK_A    | STN_A    |
|   12345 |                 1 | NTWK_B    | STN_A    |
|   12345 |                 1 | NTWK_C    | STN_B    |
|    9876 |                 2 | NTWK_F    | STN_A    |
|    9876 |                 3 | NTWK_F    | STN_A    |
|    9876 |                 3 | NTWK_F    | STN_A    |
|    9876 |                 3 | NTWK_F    | STN_A    |
+---------+-------------------+-----------+----------+
```

My current output:

```
+---------+-------------------+-----------+----------+
| ord_nbr | ord_line_rate_nbr | ntwrk_key | stn_key\ |
+---------+-------------------+-----------+----------+
|   12345 |                 1 | 3         | 2        |
|    9876 |                 2 | 1         | 1        |
|    9876 |                 3 | 1         | 1        | 
+---------+-------------------+-----------+----------+
```

My desired output:

```
+---------+-------------------+----------------------+-------------+
| ord_nbr | ord_line_rate_nbr |      ntwrk_key       |  stn_key\   |
+---------+-------------------+----------------------+-------------+
|   12345 |                 1 | NTWK_A,NTWK_B,NTWK_C | STN_A,STN_B |
|    9876 |                 2 | NTWK_F               | STN_A       |
|    9876 |                 3 | NTWK_F               | STN_A       |
+---------+-------------------+----------------------+-------------+
```

What is the best way to go about this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint:  `HAVING`.

Comment: Can you post sample data and a desired outcome please?

Comment: You need some string aggregation function, something similar to sum, max, etc but performing string concatination. Not familiar with teradata though, you'll need to check what capabilities they offer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's still no generic string aggregation function in Teradata, but several ways to implement it. The main problem is the DISTINCT part, which needs nested ROW_NUMBERs:

```
SELECT ord_nbr
  ,ord_line_rate_nbr 
  -- string aggregation
  ,Trim(Trailing ',' FROM (XmlAgg(Trim(ntwrk_key) ORDER BY ntwrk_key) (VARCHAR(1000))))
  ,Trim(Trailing ',' FROM (XmlAgg(Trim(stn_key)   ORDER BY stn_key) (VARCHAR(1000))))
FROM
 (
   SELECT
      ord_nbr
     ,ord_line_rate_nbr   
     ,CASE WHEN -- return only one of the duplicate values to emulate DISTINCT 
             Row_Number()
             Over (PARTITION BY ord_nbr,ord_line_rate_nbr, ntwrk_key 
                   ORDER BY ntwrk_key) = 1
           THEN ntwrk_key||','
           ELSE '' 
      END AS ntwrk_key 
     ,CASE WHEN
             Row_Number() -- return only one of the duplicate values to emulate DISTINCT 
             Over (PARTITION BY ord_nbr,ord_line_rate_nbr, stn_key
                   ORDER BY stn_key) = 1
           THEN stn_key||','
           ELSE ''
      END AS stn_key 
   FROM my_table
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Performance depends on overall number of rows and rows per group.